# Disable nestloops into the Postgresql JDBC connection

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I'd like to disable `nested loops` for a specific JDBC connection string (batch java application), using the PostgreSQL community driver

Is it possible to do so?

I tried this way, in vain:

```
jdbc:postgresql://xxx.yyy.zzz:5432/mydb?options=enable_nestloop=off
```

Comment: Why do you think you need that? It would be much better to optimize the statements

Comment: It's possible to run `set enable_nestloop to false` before executing the query, and setting it back to `true` before returning the connection to the pool. Far preferably to enabling it for everything!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Sometimes this is **how** you optimize the statements.  Maybe you could change (for example) random_page_cost instead, but what if there is no globally optimal setting for that?  Now you revert to the same question, how to change that other setting just for one connection, or query, or user, or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `options` connection parameter, as explained [here](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#connection-parameters):

> - **options** = String
>
> Specify 'options' connection initialization parameter.
>
> The value of this property may contain spaces or other special characters, and it should be properly encoded if provided in the connection URL. Spaces are considered to separate command-line arguments, unless escaped with a backslash (`\`); `\\` represents a literal backslash.

So that should look like

```
options=-c%20enable_nestloop%3Doff
```

But I share the horse's concern that this may be a bad idea, and you should rather tune your queries.

Comment: Thank you @laurenz-albe (and a-horse-with no-name) for your answers.

I will try your synthax!

The problem that I encountered is that the query is running fine on all our environments, except 1! 
The query doesn't look ugly, and with non-DB constraints, it is hard to obtain a rewrite!

Comment: @ThomasB: but this setting affects **all** queries you run, not just the problematic one